# Requiring a trait bound on the associated type of an inherited trait

Tags: rust

I have a trait `Foo` inheriting from another trait `Bar`. `Bar` has an associated type `Baz`. `Foo` constrains `Baz` such that `Baz` must implement `Hoge`.

```
trait Hoge {}

trait Bar {
    type Baz;
}

trait Foo: Bar where Self::Baz: Hoge {}
```

However, when I define a generic function requiring the generic type `T` to implement `Foo`,

```
// [DESIRED CODE]
fn fizz<T: Foo>(buzz: T) {
    // ...
}
```

`rustc` complains with `EO277` unless I constrain `T` explicitly:

```
fn fizz<T: Foo>(buzz: T) where T::Baz: Hoge {
    // ...
}
```

I do not understand why I need to do this. I would like to be able to write `[DESIRED CODE]`. What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Do you know if `trait Foo where ...` is conceptually valid? I see that it *compiles*, so the syntax is OK, but it just seems... strange.

Comment: You can imagine that I require some behavior of the associated type (`Baz`) so that when I use `Foo` in some implementation I can use that behavior, similar to how one might want to require some behavior of the inherited trait (`Bar`).

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Your *intent* is understandable enough (as it can be with metasyntactic variables like `Hoge`), I'm mostly asking if you've ever seen a `where` clause for a trait definition when there were no generic types; I'm not sure I have.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've ever have. Might there be some other way to achieve my intent?

Comment: @Shepmaster, well, there *are* generic types: `Self` and all associated types are essentially generic type parameters, especially `Self`. Although it does indeed look strange; I wouldn't be surprised if this was another of those things which are allowed syntactically but has no semantic meaning to the compiler (I definitely saw something like it on Rust issue tracker).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Do you know why the `where T::Baz: Hoge` above is necessary?

Comment: Nope; I'd answer if I knew.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly (or not), you have to repeat the bounds.

Last year I opened a [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28055) thinking that the type checker was being inconsistent. The code is similar to yours.

@arielb1 closed the issue and said that this was the intended behavior and gave this explanation:

> The thing is that we don't want too many bounds to be implicitly
>   available for functions, as this can lead to fragility with distant
>   changes causing functions to stop compiling. There are basically 3
>   kinds of bounds available to a function:
>
> - bounds from explicit where-clauses - e.g. `T: B` when you have that clause. This includes the "semi-explicit" `Sized` bound.
> - bounds from supertraits of explicit where-clauses - a where-clause adds bounds for its supertraits (as `trait B: A`, the `T: B` bound adds a
>     `T: A` bound).
> - bounds from the lifetime properties of arguments (outlives/implicator/implied bounds). These are only lifetime bounds,
>     and irrelevant for the current problem. [rust-lang/rfcs#1214](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1214) involved
>     them a great deal.
>
> If your bound isn't in the list, you will have to add it explicitly if
>   you want to use it. I guess this should be a FAQ entry.

Today I opened an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34106) to request that this information to be added to the docs.

Comment: I see. I strongly disagree with this idea of excluding some reasonably expected behavior simply because it might make developing Rust harder. We should figure out what users want to type and work our best to match that.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to work around this behaviour by using another associated type in `Foo` since the compiler accepts implicit bounds when part of the associated type definition ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=47a8eaddef3a612faf6e26204efe78a3)):

```rust
trait Foo: Bar<Baz = Self::HogeBaz> {
    type HogeBaz: Hoge;
}
```

The new associated type can be hidden in a helper trait to avoid having to include it in every implementation. Full example (with renaming for clarity)
([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fa65214718277fb972a6d110d32b4d4d))

```rust
trait Bound {
    fn bound();
}

trait Trait {
    type Type;
}

trait BoundedTypeHelper: Trait<Type = Self::BoundedType> {
    type BoundedType: Bound;
}

impl<T> BoundedTypeHelper for T
where
    T: Trait,
    Self::Type: Bound,
{
    type BoundedType = Self::Type;
}

trait UserTrait: BoundedTypeHelper {}

fn fizz<T: UserTrait>() {
    T::Type::bound()
}
```

I am with you in thinking that the original where-based bound ought to be treated as part of the trait definition and applied implicitly. It feels arbitrary that bounding associated types inline works but `where` clauses do not.