# Call function on overlapping trait with associate type without "where" constraint

Tags: rust

I have two overlapping traits with associated types. Given that the object for these types is the same object, I want to call a function from one trait to the other with the associated type as parameter. The following working code describes my intent.

While this code works, the where bound makes other trait implementations in my codebase quite complex. **Is there a way to achieve this result *without* the (any) where constraint?**

```rust
#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]

// module A

// 
// high-level definition in module A for actions that can be performed on entities
//
trait Action : RPC {}

// TODO: is there a way to remove these where constraints?
trait Actionable : RPCable where <Self as RPCable>::RPC: Action {
    type Action: Action;
    
    // ideally I would use 'action: Self::Action' here
    fn call(&self, action: Self::RPC) {
        // is a cast like <action as RPC> possible here that would remove the need for a where constraint?
        <Self as RPCable>::call(self, action)
    }
}

// module B

// 
// low-level definition in module B for calls that can be made on entities
//
trait RPC {}

trait RPCable {
    type RPC: RPC;
    
    fn call(&self, rpc: Self::RPC) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

// module C

// 
// create action and implement RPC
//
struct ActionImpl {}
impl Action for ActionImpl {}
impl RPC for ActionImpl {}

// 
// create entity that should be able to handle RPC and Action
//
struct Entity {}
impl Actionable for Entity {
    type Action = ActionImpl;
}
impl RPCable for Entity {
    type RPC = ActionImpl;
}

fn main() {
    let entity = Entity {};
    Actionable::call(&entity, ActionImpl{});
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5195ca0febeef04b22a2d06b7a594a7

Possibly related:

- [Requiring a trait bound on the associated type of an inherited trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600687/requiring-a-trait-bound-on-the-associated-type-of-an-inherited-trait)

Comment: The playground you have provided compiles fine after removing the `where` clause and with no other changes.

Comment: I see you want to use `Self::Action` instead of `Self::RPC`. But for that to work `Self::Action` and `Self::RPC` have to be the same type - not just implement the same trait. Maybe `trait Actionable : RPCable<RPC=Self::Action>` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Although I have to question the wisdom of having two identical traits, where one depends on the other in this way... seems like one should be a marker trait. Like `Iterator` and `FusedIterator`

Comment: Can you provide an example where the constraints make your code complex?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @trentcl for pointing out that the provided code actually worked without the *where* bound. I must have made an unminded change before posting it here that suddenly made it work. Surprised by it functioning I took a look again at my codebase to see what was going wrong.

My code was expecting `Action` as parameter higher up, but since it was an associated type it couldn't match it with `RPC`. I needed to either provide a where bound like `where Actionable<Action=<Self as RPCable>::RPC>` but that kept resulting in cyclic trait dependency issues, since `Actionable` and `RPCable` were alwasy the same object. Finally I found that on the highest level where Action was actually stored in a struct, I could cast it to RPC without a *where* bound by doing something like this:

```rust
struct Diff {
    action: Action
}

impl DiffTrait for Diff {
    type Object : Actionable;

    fn action(&self) -> &<Self::Object as Actionable>::Action { 
        &self.action 
    }

    fn rpc(&self) -> &<Self::Object as RPCable>::RPCObject {
        &self.action
    }
}
```

After which I could use the right variant for different parameter type invocations.

Thank you!